# Windows 10 won't boot on El Capitan

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows

Every time I try to boot into Windows 10 , I get this message in a black screen:

**"no bootable device – insert boot disk and press any key"**

Note that it was working before.

Any ideas?

**diskutil list**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS empty                   209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            199.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS em                      650.0 MB   disk0s4
   5:           Linux Filesystem                         119.8 GB   disk0s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS disk0s10                22.0 GB    disk0s6
   7:                  Apple_HFS e                       343.7 MB   disk0s7
   8:                        EFI NO NAME                 2.8 GB     disk0s8
   9:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                149.6 GB   disk0s9
  10:           Windows Recovery                         471.9 MB   disk0s10
```

**diskutil cs list**

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

**sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0**

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500277790720; sectorsize=512; blocks=977105060
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 977105059

      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     409640  389032888      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  389442528    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  390712064    1269536      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  391981600  234019258      5  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
  626000858   42952704      6  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  668953562     262144
  669215706     671368      7  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  669887074    8617504
  678504578    5541888      8  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
  684046466  292136960      9  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  976183426     921600     10  GPT part - DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
  977105026          1
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

**sudo fdisk /dev/disk0**

```
Disk: /dev/disk0 geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55

         Starting       Ending
 id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: EE 1023 255  63 - 1023 255  63 [         1 -  977105059] <Unknown ID>
2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Answer (score 1):

So after almost 48 hours of trial and error this is what saved the day.

- Boot on recovery mode and `csrutil disable`
- boot back on OSX
- Run `diskutil list`
- Find BOOTCAMP from 'diskutil list' and check the **ID** (the very first number at the start of the line)
- `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`

**now just input those single letters and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time**

- <kbd>r</kbd> go to the recovery & transformation menu
- <kbd>h</kbd> create a new hybrid MBR.
- **ID** add partition ID to the MBR.  Your’s may be different! Use what you got from line 4 above.
- <kbd>y</kbd> if you are asked “Place EFI GPT (0xEE) partition first in MBR (good for GRUB)?”
- accept the default MBR hex code of 07
- <kbd>y</kbd> set the bootable flag
- <kbd>n</kbd> do not protect more partitions
- <kbd>o</kbd> print (display) the MBR.
- <kbd>w</kbd> Recovery/transformation command (write partition table to disk)
- <kbd>y</kbd> Say yes to question: do you want to proceed.